# Pulling doctype using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Here is an html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

</html>
```

I am trying to pull the Doctype keyword from the above code using beautiful soup. On searching on internet I found this:

`soup.contents[0]` as a code to get the DOCTYPE. But when I printed it I get the result as 'html'
How to get the Keyword doctype here?

Comment: The doctype isn't a proper element; it's a [preamble](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#the-doctype), like a header.

Comment: can I get it in a string or list?

Comment: try httplib2 as I showed, it should be fine for HTML5 pages!

Comment: I want to do it using beautifulsoup because I am learning how to use it, Is it possible to to acheive this using bs4?